# Python decimal sum returning wrong value

Tags: python, fixed-point

I'm using decimal module to avoid float rounding errors. In my case the values are money so I want two decimal places.

To do that I do `decimal.getcontext().prec = 2` but then I get some surprising results which make me think I'm missing something. In this code the first assertion works, but the second fails

```py
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal

assert Decimal("3000") + Decimal("20") == 3020

getcontext().prec = 2

assert Decimal("3000") + Decimal("20") == 3020  # fails
```

Since `3000` and `20` are integers I was expecting this to hold, but I get `3000` instead. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: I think prec is the number of sig figs, not the number of digits after the decimal? The manual is not super clear about this.

Comment: Read `prec` as significant figures. You cannot represent 3020 with only 2 s.f. The next value that can be represented after 3000 with 2 s.f. is 3100.

Comment: Just print the `Decimal("3000") + Decimal("20")` value. You'll see how `perc` works.

Comment: *"In my case the values are money so I want two decimal places."* You might consider using ints for this: instead of storing a float/decimal number of dollars/euros/etc, store an integer number of cents. Then divide that by 100 only when you need to display the value. Of course 300000 + 2000 = 30200 in integer arithmetic, with no rounding concerns.

Comment: 300000 + 2000 = 302000, I should of course have said :)

Comment: Yes @slothrop, in fact I was doing that, but I have to keep scaling up and down, and multiplication is not trivial, so I decided to try decimal instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decimal` does not implement fixed-point arithmetic directly. It implements base 10 *floating*-point arithmetic. The precision (`prec`) is the total number of significant digits retained and has nothing to do with the position of the radix point.

Try displaying the computed value in your last example:

```py
>>> Decimal("3000") + Decimal("20")
Decimal('3.0E+3')
```

The exact result (3020) is rounded back to the 2 (because you set `prec` to 2) most significant digits, so the trailing "20" is thrown away.

If, e.g., you want 2 places *after* the decimal point, you'll have to arrange for that yourself. Search [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for the question "Once I have valid two place inputs, how do I maintain that invariant throughout an application?".

Comment: Does the doc describe this meaning of the precision somewhere? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Unsure, & I'm not going to read all the docs to find out ;-) In general, there's a great deal about `decimal` left unsaid in the Python docs, because it's an implementation of an external standard (IBB'sGeneral Decimal Arithmetic Specification). That's were to find expositions of the model, and excruciating details https://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html

Comment: @KellyBundy  The closest the docs get to explaining what the precision setting does are the statements "The context precision does not affect how many digits are stored. That is determined exclusively by the number of digits in value. For example, Decimal('3.00000') records all five zeros even if the context precision is only three." and  "There are many ways to express the same value. The numbers 200, 200.000, 2E2, and .02E+4 all have the same value at various precisions."

Comment: The worst part of the docs is that the one example given directly under the description of the `prec` setting is showing the results of `Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)` so it implies its setting decimal places, not significant digits.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in comments, the `prec` field specifies the precision of the overall value, i.e., significant figures.

To set decimal places, you would use the [`quantize()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize), like

```
>>> (Decimal("3000") + Decimal("20")).quantize(Decimal("1.00"))
Decimal('3020.00')
```

Note that you shouldn't need to quantize every result -- adding and subtracting two Decimals that have 2dp will produce a result with 2dp too. You would to quantize any time you divide, or any time you multiply by a non-integer value.